# How to pretty print this in python using function?

Tags: python

So I need to pretty print in python using the txt file working on it trying to find answer everywhere but I failed miserably ;p  so time to ask question.

I have txt file with this input:

```
10
Robert Jack                   
Robert Gary
Lizzie Dave
Lena
Mia    Dave
Mia    Caroline
Rafael
Robert Nick
```

and I need to  pretty print this using function to look like this:

```
Robert -> Jack, Gary, Nick 
Jack   -> Robert
```

etc.

```
while True:
    cusInp = input("Type what file you would like to open? = ")
    if cusInp == "nw_data1.txt":
        # print(fileOne.read())
        display_input=input("Would you like to see the the network?" + "Y/N:  "  )
        while True:
            if display_input=="Y":

                with open("nw_data1.txt", "r") as file:
                    Social_NW=[file.read()]
                for name in Social_NW:
                    if name[0] not in friends:
                         friends[name[0]] = [name[1]]
                    else:
                         friends[name[0]].append(name[1])
                         pprint(friends)
                         break
            elif display_input=="N":
                print("Program has been closed,Thank you for your time.")
                break
            else:
                print("Wrong input please use Y/N")
                display_input=input("Would you like to see the the network?" + "Y/N:  "  )
                continue
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my take on this:

```
import io
import re

data = """
Robert Jack                   
Robert Gary
Lizzie Dave
Lena
Mia    Dave
Mia    Caroline
Rafael
Robert Nick
"""


def parse_data(data_to_parse: str) -> dict:
    graph = {}
    file = io.StringIO(data_to_parse)
    pattern = re.compile('^(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<friend>[a-zA-Z]+)\s*$')
    for line in file:
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m:
            if m['name'] not in graph:
                graph[m['name']] = []
            graph[m['name']].append(m['friend'])
            if m['friend'] not in graph:
                graph[m['friend']] = []
            graph[m['friend']].append(m['name'])
    return graph


def print_graph(graph_to_print: dict):
    for k, v in graph_to_print.items():
        print(k, ' -> ', ', '.join(v))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = parse_data(data)
    print_graph(g)
```

You need to adapt the code a little bit to match your own I/O setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm quite new to all this the data I have is in txt file not sure how to take it out of there rather than have it in data variable

Comment: `with io.open(file_path) as file:` instead of `file = io.StringIO(text)`
make `file_path` an augument of the function or better, pass `file` to the function and open the file in the caller.